# Method get called automatically when template get completely loaded in angular / ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I want a method get called automatically when template get completely loaded. I have tried **lifecycle hooks of ionic as well as angular** and I have also tried to **call method from template**.
html

My HTML file contains the following:

```html
<h1>{{ myMethod() }}</h1>
```

But this is calling the `myMethod` function many times.

Comment: What does `myMethod` do, and why is it not acceptable for this function to be called multiple times?

Comment: I want to load map on device when side menu button is clicked. That's why it is unacceptable to be called multiple times.

Comment: So `myMethod` loads the map? Shouldn't this then be called by the button's click event? You should assume bindings like this in the view _will_ be called multiple times.

Comment: did you try `ngAfterViewChecked`? that's the last lifecycle hook which runs after components & all its children are fully rendered with DOM changes applied.

Comment: @David On clicking side menu button. It reset root page again. And load new page. Hence click event is not of much use.

Comment: @dee I have tried it too. Problem with **ngAfterViewChecked** it is called many times.

Comment: sure but, what prevents you to put a property flag on component `ranAlready:boolean = false`, set it to `true` on first `ngAfterViewChecked` run and call the function only if that boolean is false?

Comment: @deezg template is does not load on second or third call of **ngAfterViewChecked**.

Comment: i am not actually sure what exactly do you mean by 'how would i know that template is loaded'?

Comment: I want to call a method when template get displayed on screen.

Comment: then use what i proposed. check also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41391939/angular2-ngafterviewchecked-is-called-many-times-how-to-call-a-method-just-o

Comment: I have tried all the **angular and ionic lifecycle hooks.**

Comment: that doesn't help. What is the problem with `ngAfterViewChecked` in particular? does it run too early for you or it doesn't run too early but it runs many times?

Comment: there are two problem with **ngAfterViewChecked**. First it runs many times and second it executes from **"before loading template"** till **"template get loaded"** but I am not able to know after which **call** template get loaded.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but i am pretty sure something is missing in this question description. People are counting precise scrolling positions with `ngAfterViewChecked': https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31171084/how-to-call-function-after-dom-renders-in-angular2 Its hard for me to believe you wouldn't be able to do what you're saying.

Comment: @deezg no brother I am not getting you wrong. I know you are doing your best to help me in my problem. I really want to thank you for this. You can see [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1y-xLc_4-p9aq8jGqpZCB0tjSg0WvwKSJ) I have uploaded screenshot of each call. Main problem with this is that I don't know which before which call my template gets loaded on display.

Comment: does that particular component you're waiting to load have children components?

Comment: Yes. It have 1 div child component and nested components.

Comment: and, 2 questions then: 1) are you're waiting for all of them to load and be shown on screen before you fire your function or you need some particular one to be loaded? 2) does any of your child/sibling components have any kind of async calls before they load?

Comment: 1) I want to wait for a particular component to be shown on screen before I can fire my function.
2)Yes I have async calls before they load.

Comment: have you tried isolating that particular 'thing' into a single component (that will have no children) and use its `ngOnViewInit/ngOnViewChecked`? if needed, you could emit `@Output()` event from it to parent if parent is the one that should load the map. btw, this also might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40938422/angular-2-calling-jquery-after-rendering-elements-after-consuming-api

Comment: I will try this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you need to call `myMethod()` only one time, it is better to use **`ionViewDidLoad`**. Because this event  fired only when a view is stored in memory. This event is NOT fired on entering a view that is already cached. you could find out more information from [here](https://blog.ionicframework.com/navigating-lifecycle-events/).

So if you need to call the method (`myMethod()`) even after this event is fired it is better to use timeout inside this event to call your method. Give desire timeout that match with your scenario.

Sample code:

```js
ionViewDidLoad() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    myMethod();
  }, 300);
}
```

Hope this will help to solve your problem.

Comment: Doesn't it make unnecessary delay in the app.

Comment: but this is the only place match with your problem. try to adjust that delay according to your scenario in effective and efficient way. this is not unnecessary delay. because it is necessary to solve your problem. Also this delay effect to your app only one time.

Comment: I think of this earlier but I don't want to use it. Now I realised that there is no other way and have to use timeout only. Thanks

Comment: np :)  if you find out another way to achieve this don't forget to update here.. ;)

Comment: sure. I will :)

Comment: what happens if he changes the structure/number/complexity of sibling components and their children? should he readjust the timeout?

Comment: when it's fired the `ionViewDidLoad`, the other components  and their children in that view has been already loaded. that part would be handled by the ionic. timeout effect only after that part

Comment: i am not that familiar with ionic to know all the details but whenever i see a need to 'adjust timeouts' i am very cautious. my first question in approaching this would be: why 300ms? or, if you would have written whatever number of ms - i'd still ask 'why that particular number'?

Comment: i just put that number only as a e.g in sample code. If you want you could reduce until match with what ever scenario you deal with.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should go for **`ngAfterViewInit`** life cycle hook. ngAfterViewInit() is called after the view is initially rendered.

```js
export class YourComponent implements AfterViewInit {    
  constructor() {    
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    myMethod();
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried lifecycle hook of angular as well as ionic. These methods are called before rendering template.

Comment: @TonyStark ok, did you try ionViewDidLoad() {
    // Put here the code you want to execute
  } ?